# decodeURIComponent inside *ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm calling an API that retrieves a JSON object, and I'm doing a *ngFor for that object. The problem I have is that one of the fields is coming to URI encoded, and I cannot / do not know how to apply decodeURIComponent on a *ngFor loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let note of NotesList">
                        <div class="alert alert-custom">
                            <h5>{{note.notetitle}}</h5>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="smallfont">{{note.notecontent}}</div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="supersmallfont">By {{note.username}} on {{note.dateentered}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The field that is URI encoded is notecontent.

Is it possible to decode it from the HTML file? Thanks.

Comment: You should read  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129121/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-in-angular-9#comment115143327_65129121    There must be a better solution than the one accepted here.   I don't know it.

Comment: Very interesting Rickz. In my case, there are a maximum of 7 records, so I guess performance wont be an issue, but I will consider it for larger arrays. Thanks a lot Rick.

Comment: I am thinking that using a pipe would be a good solution. See https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to care about the loop, Ivy takes care of that for you. Just create a function in your component that does the work and use it in the template:

```
decode(content: string){
  return decodeUriComponent(content);
}
```

and then in your html template:

```
  <hr>
    <div class="smallfont"> {{ decode(note.notecontent) }}</div>
  <hr>
```

Comment: Amazing. I didnt know I could call a function from the HTML. That opens tons of doors for everything. Thanks Omar.